# Mongoid 4 multiparameter attributes with Rails 4

Tags: mongoid, multiparameter

I am using a date helper in a rails 4 form.

```
= date_select :press_article, :date
```

My model:

```
class PressArticle
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::MultiParameterAttributes
  field :title, type: String
  field :excerpt, type: String
  field :body, type: String
  field :date, type: Date
  field :press_name, type: String
  field :press_logo, type: String
  field :article_image, type: String
  field :article_url, type: String
end
```

However, when I try to save a new press_article I get the following error:

```
uninitialized constant Mongoid::MultiParameterAttributes
```

Help anyone?

Answer (score 0):

`Mongoid::MultiParameterAttributes` was removed from Mongoid and the entire thing is up in the air at the moment with Rails 4.

https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/8189